Modify frames of a non-visible object
I want to extend an animation that has already been created. Originally, it has 550 frames, but I want to lengthen it to 750.
To do this, I want to move all the frames from 250 onwards.
I tried to disable "only show selected" option on the timeline to see all keyframes, but it only works for objects that are visible. Is there a way to see the keyframes of absolutely all objects, including non-visible ones? or maybe another way to achieve what I want?

In the Dopesheet window, there's a button that enables the "Show Hidden" function, next to the "Only selected" one.


Good to note that, because Blender makes hidden objects non-selectable, you need to enable "show hidden" AND disable "only selected"
